# Does any of the upcoming AX releases include Business Process Flows such as utilized in CRM 2013

Tags: integration, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

We are currently looking at a massive integration between AX 2012 R2 and CRM 2013. CRM 2013 has a great feature called Business Process Flow's which enable you to guide user's through the business processes.

We have a requirement for that tool but in AX. We don't want to build an integration from AX to CRM just to achieve the functionality, or else build the functionality ourselves if it turns out that AX will be releasing a similar feature in an upcoming update.

Don't know if this is the correct place to post queries about upcoming releases. But might be a good place to discuss where people could find information about upcoming releases so that developers don't develop custom features only for a new release to render them obsolete.

I've found the following links but none mention anything about Business Process Flow for AX:

http://rcpmag.com/articles/2014/01/13/retail-features-in-dynamics-ax-2012-r3.aspx

http://www.mwdata.dk/news/new-exciting-features-for-dynamics-ax-2012-coming-up/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dax/archive/2013/11/05/microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-r3-a-preview.aspx

Are there any official Microsoft channels you can go through to get more details?

Comment: I consider guessing on future functionality of AX outside the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: I'd agree, I was hoping more whether someone knew something concrete about upcoming features, say if someone was working on new functionality within Microsoft. Information a Microsoft employee might have

Comment: Partners and employees alike are bound by a nondisclosure agreement.

Answer (score 0):

AX has already [workflow built-in](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg723980.aspx). How does this match CRM Business Process Flow?

The feature list looks close, but the user interface may not.

Comment: CRM Business Process Flow, can set up logical steps that a user needs to follow to complete a business process. So for example, to complete a marketing campaign, you'd set up tasks whereby the user would need to gather a marketing list, email marketing list, check responses, record money spent and then analyse campaign. Whereas AX workflow is more akin to user posts journal, journal approval must be done by manager, journal gets posted. It's not as wideranging and doesn't force users into doing the whole business process. Its more a subset of the busines process

Answer (score 0):

AX 2012 has a “Business Process Modeler”. You can use Business process modeler to create, view, and modify business-process libraries and flowcharts for Microsoft Dynamics AX. The Business process modeler helps in aligning AX processes with industry-standard processes as described by American Productivity & Quality Center (APQC). The flowcharts are also there so partners/clients can perform fit-gap analysis between their business needs and the default processes in Microsoft Dynamics AX. You can also add new business processes and create flowcharts for processes that are not already defined in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012.

You can get instructions on how to access these processes in TechNet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268623.aspx